# aws linux imagmagick-native npm installing is failing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

I have no idea why this install is failing.

I am trying to get imagemagick-native to install on the ec2 instance of amazon-linux. 
Any help would be awesome! I have all of the compilers and stuff needed on the system level for linux.

```
ake: *** [Release/obj.target/imagemagick/src/imagemagick.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/thor/node_modules/imagemagick-native/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ec2-user/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/ec2-user/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/thor/node_modules/imagemagick-native
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! imagemagick-native@0.2.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the imagemagick-native@0.2.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the imagemagick-native package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls imagemagick-native
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/home/ec2-user/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/thor
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/thor/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick already in the OS prior to trying to add the node package? It's notorious for being annoying to install due to the dependencies and package repos having outdated versions. I'd double check that it's all working first

Comment: installed the dependencies recommended by the repo.

ImageMagick-c++: ""     
ImageMagick-c++-devel: ""

do I need sudo yum install ImageMagick?

Comment: this is really stupid beanstalk elastic is so difficult to get set up.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: No this is still an issue, and have not figured it out.